# How to get worked mod_wsgi with .pyo files only (without .py)?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to start apache + mod_wsgi and I have strong restriction to put source .py files onto server, so I compile them first and put .pyo files onto server.

That's what I have in apache conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonPath /var/wwwroot/
WSGIPythonOptimize 1
WSGIScriptAlias /home /var/wwwroot/home.pyo
```

But mod_wsgi raises the error (cut from apache error log):

```
Failed to parse WSGI script file '/var/wwwroot/home.pyo'.
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/wwwroot/home.pyo'.
File "/var/wwwroot/home.pyo", line 1
      m\xf2
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to google but couldn't find an answer for does mod_wsgi work with pre-compiled python code.

Comment: Are the restrictions to do with what of your IP you may put up, or is something blocking `.py` files? If not, do something like have `wsgi_launch.py` which just does `from home import *`.

Comment: Do you mean putting all the pre-compiled code as earlier and putting one not compiled .py file that loads modules and runs them? It's a good idea if there's no chance to get pre-compiled code working. It looks like workaround, but I believe there's a simple way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: OK, turned it into an answer with a bit more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on the mod_wsgi list at:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/5da316e3480eab7f

The short answer is that only the WSGI script file needs to be source code and as others have pointed out, just have that have appropriate lines to set up sys.path if necessary and then import the actual WSGI application entry point from the .pyo version of module elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward workaround is to add next to your `home.pyo` an extra file which just contains `from home import *`. You could call it `foo.py`, you could call it `home.wsgi`, you could call it `the-quick-brown-fox-ate-the-lazy-dog` if you wanted to. (So if you're having problems with it having the extension ".py", it doesn't matter.)

Comment: I don't have problems having files with .py extension, I have problems running pre-compiled code. I'm restricted to put sources onto production server. I'm awared that python pre-compiled code can be decompiled, but anyway. Thanks a lot, I'll try your workaround if no chance to do it 'right' :)

Comment: @Ruslan: "Doing it 'right'" means not relying on the .pyo's.  I suppose you could try decompiling them if you insist.

Answer (score 1):

mod_wsgi doesn't work with only *.pyo files, I ran into this exact problem and banged my head against the wall for a couple hours trying to figure it out.

mod_wsgi does not work without the python source code in regular old '.py' format.

Comment: ohhh... thanks! I've almost broken my head already and I'm coming to the same conclusion. Seems like I'm going back to mod_python, sad but true.

Comment: @Ruslan: it doesn't seem to me a big problem when you can just have a single line source Python file to bridge the gap. Definitely not enough to go back to mod_python for if mod_wsgi will perform better.